# IE and Active Directory authentication

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, networking, active-directory, iis-7.5

I've set up an intranet site that uses AD to determine premissions. Works great with IE.

Occasionally users go to the site and are asked for credentials even though they are using IE. I'm guessing IE didn't send the AD information the site needed, probably because of security settings.

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5 set up with Windows Authentication.

In the code it asks for the NT user name when the page is being loaded using:

```
    Dim ss As SoftwareStorage = New SoftwareStorage()
    Dim username As String
    username = ss.returnUserName()
    ...
    <input type="hidden" id="domainName" value="<% Response.Write(username)%>" />
    ...
    Dim ftpUser As System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal
    Public Function returnUserName() As String
       ftpUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User
       Return (ftpUser.Identity.Name)
    End Function
```

I looked at Wireshark feeds of a good(working) and a bad(not working) http connection.
The good one has the following info on the two inital http calls:

```
    GET /foo/index.aspx HTTP/1.1 , NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE
    GET /foo/index.aspx HTTP/W.W , NTLMSSP_AUTH, User: MYDOMAIN\foobar
```

The bad one has the following on the same two initial calls:

```
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    GET / HTTP/1.1
```

So it would appear that IE Is not sending the correct header information on request in the one instance (IE 9, Vista) and is sending the correct header information in the other (IE 9, Win7).

I'm hoping someone can help me solve this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For safety (security) reasons, IE will not send credentials to a server unless it is certain that it can trust the server.  This is especially true for automatically sending domain credentials.  So, to ensure that IE has maximum trust for your server, you can go into (browser menu) Tools, Internet Options, Security and explicitly set the name of your server as being in the "Intranet" zone.  The Intranet zone has a much higher trust level than ordinary "trusted" servers.
Safety disclaimer: Don't explicitly identify a server as being an intranet server unless you really do trust it.

For more information, read up on Security Zones for IE.

Also, from IIS (Authentication), make sure "Windows Authentication" is enabled (anonymous is disabled) and (select "Windows Authentication", click "Providers" (right)) make sure NTLM is at the top of the list.

Comment: Yep. checked that. Which is why I added more information. The fail, I think, happens when the codebehind attempts to acquire the username. I have two machines (both on the intranet) and my second machine dulicates the problem users are experiencing.

Comment: I see you are using vb.net.  Have you tried My.User. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/a3da82hw(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Also, from IIS (Authentication), make sure "Windows  Authentication" is enabled (anonymous is disabled) and (select "Windows Authentication", click "Providers" (right)) make sure NTLM is at the top of the list.

Comment: You. Da. MAN! I did not have to change my code to My.User. What worked are the IIS changes you sugested! Thanks! (I edited your answer to include your IIS changes)